# What is the correct places for parameters in OKHttp in a multipart form call?

Tags: php, android, forms, https, okhttp

I'm trying to replicate a jpg file upload using OKHttp to a multipart form on a PHP server.  I believe,  I got some of the parameters in the wrong place,  I don't have the familiarity with multipart forms in http and the nomenclature.

**Here's what I'm trying to accomplish**

Post the parameters (name value pairs):
myuser, token, types   to https://www.somesite.com/jpgphotoupload.php

I'm then making a multipart form request with method POST, with the following:
path: https://www.somesite.com/jpgphotoupload.php

file data: JPEG compressed image data of size 480 x 640 *(This I understand)*

mimeType: image/jpeg  *(This I understand)*

**Not sure where the following name value pairs should be placed as part of the multipart form request, tried addFormDataPart**

parameters: again the parameter form above, (myuser, token, types)

name: imagefile

fileName: myname.jpg

In addition, here's what else may be pertinent

```
            "Connection" , "Keep-Alive"
            "ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data"
            "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
```

Here's the code that I have currently.

```
MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPG = MediaType.parse("image/jpg");

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                        .addPart(
                                Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"imagefile\""),
                                RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, new File("/storage/emulated/0/download/camerapic.jpg")))
                        .addFormDataPart("myuser", getprefmyuser(getBaseContext()))
                        .addFormDataPart("token", getpreftoken(getBaseContext()))
                        .addFormDataPart("types", "type1")
                        .addFormDataPart("fileName", "myname.jpg")
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .header("myuser", getprefmyuser(getBaseContext()))
                        .header("token", getpreftoken(getBaseContext()))
                        .header("type", "car")
                        .url("https://www.somesite.com/jpgphotoupload.php")
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build();

            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
        ... 

        return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case, I needed to upload a video to an Amazon S3 bucket. This is what worked for me.

```
File sourceFile = new File(myUri);

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                    .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("keyOne", "valueOne")
                    .addFormDataPart("keyTwo", "valueTwo")
                    .addFormDataPart("file", "myFileName", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/quicktime"), sourceFile))
                    .build();
```

Comment: I need to upload a video that is capture on a mobile device, so I am guessing `.mp4` so what should I specify for `RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/quicktime"), sourceFile)`? do I still use `quicktime`? (I don't know much about videos)

Comment: and your video source is that just a file? as in `new File(myFileName)`? Here I am assuming that myFileName is the exact value passed before.

Comment: Yes, my video source was the ```sourceFile``` in the code provided (a video file written to disk). IIRC, ```myFileName``` is what you are telling it the file's name is and can be whatever you want it to be. The ```File``` object is used to get the data, but I don't think the original uri/name matters.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, actually. Looking at it now, it looks like we've since changed the code. We set the contentType as ```video/3gp``` now. We also use Amazon's libraries now so I can't find exactly what I was doing here originally. If you want to go that route, you can put these in your ```build.gradle``` under ```dependencies``` --- ```compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.7'``` --- ```compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.7'```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676044/multipartbuilder-cant-be-resolved-in-okhttp3-0-0-rc1