# MultipartBuilder can't be resolved in okhttp:3.0.0-RC1

Tags: android, okhttp

I have used **okhttp** and It's working fine with following dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
```

Recently I have updated with:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
```

It shows error like **`MultipartBuilder`** can't be resolved.

I am uploading image with my [Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34127008/1318946l) of Uploading File.

Is there any way to achieve the same thing using `okhttp:3.0.0-RC1` ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is called  [MultipartBody.Builder](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/MultipartBody.kt) now. From the ChangeLog:

> Form and Multipart bodies are now modeled. We've replaced the opaque
>   FormEncodingBuilder with the more powerful FormBody and
>   FormBody.Builder combo. Similarly we've upgraded MultipartBuilder into
>   MultipartBody, MultipartBody.Part, and MultipartBody.Builder.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).