# Postman Java code snipped Okhttp not compatible

Tags: java, postman, okhttp

I'm using Postman version 8.5.1 and I'm trying to use the code OkHTTP code snippets.
It seems some statements are not working like ...

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
```

However this seems to work ...

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
```

Also this doesn't work ...

```
  .addFormDataPart("file","test.jpg",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),new File("/Users/tm/Desktop/test.jpg")))
```

It mentions something about a wrong RequestBody object ...

I'm using this maven repo ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the import statement

```
 import com.squareup.okhttp.*;
```

What version of the okhttp is fully compatible with the Postman code snippets?
Which maven repo should be used?

It seems there is also a okhttp3 ...

Comment: Why are you bringing up postman?  What does this have to do with your problem using the okhttp library?  Show us a more complete example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the code snippets are okhttp3 and not okhttp...

This seems to work ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

import statement

```
 import okhttp3.*;
```

Comment: Also, we would get the error "MultipartBuilder.Builder cannot be resolved to a 
 type".If we have below line

new MultipartBuilder.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

And the fix would be to replace MultipartBuilder with  MultipartBody as given below.

 RequestBody body = new  MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676044/multipartbuilder-cant-be-resolved-in-okhttp3-0-0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

How are you using the snippets from Postman, where are you pasting these ?
Please post a whole snippet of your code. In general get the latest version of okhttp --> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/4.2.2.